# How can I use BERT model to predict sentence semantic similarity to a dataset with no label?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, bert-language-model

I am a beginner in using BERT model. I am following a tutorial from Keras website [https://keras.io/examples/nlp/semantic_similarity_with_bert/#:~:text=Introduction,sentence%20semantic%20similarity%20with%20Transformers](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/semantic_similarity_with_bert/#:%7E:text=Introduction,sentence%20semantic%20similarity%20with%20Transformers).

But the dataset they used in the example has label variable ('similarity'). Is there any tutorial or any guidance where BERT model is used to predict semantic similarity to a data which has only Text column?

Comment: You could check out [sentence transformers](https://www.sbert.net/docs/quickstart.html#comparing-sentence-similarities)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, BERT is meant to be used in supervised problems like the example in the Keras site. If your dataset is composed only with text columns you can do the following: extract the features with BERT model and use Kmeans to cluster your data in separate groups. More info on KMeans [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/k-means-clustering-for-unsupervised-machine-learning-afd96fbd37ac) and this [post](https://medium.com/ether-labs/bert-for-unsupervised-text-tasks-fa6e9ce5d133) has more details on this approach.